# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I keep this while running `php artisan migrate`

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

**My Environment**

- Laravel Framework version 5.1.20 (LTS)
- Laravel Installer version 1.2.0
- PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Oct  2 2015 08:55:56)
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for osx10.10 (x86_64)

---

**.env file**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=http://localhost/
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=****

DB_HOST=http://localhost/
DB_DATABASE=name-local
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
UNIX_SOCKET = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

---

That data-base `name-local` is exist in my local database.

Any hints / suggestions will be a huge help for me.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Check your `DB_HOST` on your `.env` file

`DB_HOST=http://localhost/` --> `DB_HOST=localhost`

---

**Result:**

I can migrate peacefully now.

```
php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
```

Comment: Just commenting if anyone else falls here too, my problem was that my MySQL host server was down. Pay attention to that. It may be the cause as well.

Answer (score 31):

Set `DB_HOST=localhost` and run the following artisan command

`php artisan config:clear` it will help you, clear cached config

Answer (score 26):

I finally figured out what was causing this error for me. I'm using docker but I wasn't running `php artisan migrate` from the shell in the container. I was just running it in Terminal after navigating to the laravel project folder.
Go to your docker dashboard and launch the CLI for the laravel container in the image for your project. Then run the migrate command.

Comment: This helped! However, could you please explain why it will work from the Container CLI but not the WSL Terminal? (I'm pretty new to Sail / Docker. I usually use Laragon)

Comment: This solution works for me : ) @Bennett - Im also wondering how it is possible that migrate command works fine in macOS terminal and seed command must be ran via docker container cli - someone can explain that?

Comment: This guided me to the right direction. I'm using Docker and was running "php" instead of "./vendor/bin/sail"

Comment: Here's my shot at answering @JakubUjvvary and @.Bennett. The container is essentially a virtual computer running inside your machine right? So it's running its own OS and has its own versions of php, MySQL, Sail, git, etc. But, through trickery, the container shares some directories with the outer OS (macOS, etc.). So some operations run on those files from the outer OS will happen to work. But remember you might have different configurations on the container software than you do on the outer computer. Hence some problems.

Answer (score 16):

You might also get this error if you are using sail, and you run
`php artisan migrate`
instead of:

`sail artisan migrate`

Comment: or vessel package which you should run migration as `./vessel artisan migrate`

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue on laravel 8.x after a fresh install. Setting `DB_HOST=0.0.0.0` fixed it for me.

Remember to run `php artisan config:clear` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while running Laravel from DDEV.

Solution: run  "php artisan migrate" within your DDEV container.

```
user@ddev-project:  ddev ssh

user@ddev-project:/var/www/html$ php artisan migrate
```

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using docker first find your docker container with docker ps command and then execute php artisan migrate command form your container with this command

```
docker exec -it {containerId}
```

bash

Answer (score 0):

I got an error because I was running Laravel on docker using Laravel Sail. [James answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553508/5922816) helped me solve the issue.

Run `sail artisan migrate` instead of `php artisan migrate`

The reason why I didn't know about this is because I followed the basic installation documentation for docker.

> When reading the Laravel documentation, you will often see references to Composer, Artisan, and Node / NPM commands that do not reference Sail. Those examples assume that these tools are installed on your local computer. If you are using Sail for your local Laravel development environment, you should execute those commands using Sail:

```
# Running Artisan commands locally...
php artisan queue:work
 
# Running Artisan commands within Laravel Sail...
sail artisan queue:work
```

Specific documentation on sail can be found here: [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail)

Answer (score 0):

Solving php_network_getaddresses Error with **Laravel Sail**
If you encounter the `[2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` error when running artisan migrate with Laravel Sail, it could be due to the underlying environment.

Laravel Sail provides a convenient way to run Laravel applications using Docker, and it might require using the sail command for certain Artisan commands.

To resolve the issue, try running the migrate command using sail:

```
sail artisan migrate
```

This ensures that the Artisan command is executed within the Sail environment and utilizes the appropriate settings.

Remember to replace sail with the relevant command if you've customized your Sail aliases.

This approach should help you successfully execute migrations in the Laravel Sail environment. If you have further questions or encounter issues, feel free to ask for assistance.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `SESSION_DRIVER` to `file`. Worked for me.

Comment: How does this help with a misconfigured database connection while running a migration from the command line?