# How do I send email using laravel with mailtrap

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send email using laravel

Here is .env config after creating an account and putting my password and username inside the .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

My create.blade the form for my mail

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Contact details')
@section('content')
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>

    <form action="/contact" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="pb-5">
            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ old('email')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="pb-4">
            {{ $errors->first('email') }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Message: </label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="pb-4">
            {{ $errors->first('message') }}
        </div>

        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
    </form>
    @endsection
```

My contact-form.blade for mailtrap

```
@component('mail::message')
# thank you for your message


    <strong>Name: </strong>{{ $data['name'] }}
    <strong>Email: </strong>{{ $data['email'] }}

    <strong>Message</strong>
    {{ $data['message'] }}
@endcomponent
```

and then my ContactFormMail.php controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ContactFormMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.contact.contact-form');
    }
}
```

Kindly help me for this, I have been stuck on this the whole night

Comment: Here is the error message

Comment: Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known #0]
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact

Comment: I don't think the issue is your mail config, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260172/sqlstatehy000-2002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-nodename-no) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can follow the link below to it in a simple way 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications

note: dont forget to add this in your .env file

> MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls